# Fill HTML Form with PHP data using field's ID as identifier

Tags: java, php, forms, class, fill

I have this array named `$clientinfo`:

```
[id] => 1
[dlastname] => Brown
[dfirstname] => George
[dmob] => 189328937
[dlandline] => 92839283
```

and so on... I want to populate this form:

```
<li class="hidden"><label for="did">unique id:</label><input id="did" type="text" name="did" style="background-color:gray" readonly="readonly" /></li>
<li class="firstcell"><label for="dlastname">lastname:</label><input id="dlastname" type="text" name="dlastname" /></li>
<li class="middlecell"><label for="dfirstname">firstname: </label><input id="dfirstname" type="text" name="dfirstname"  /></li> 
<li class="middlecell"><label for="dmob">mob </label><input id="dmob" type="text" name="dmob" /></li>
```

and so on...

I am able to fill the fields using php by adding this at the end of each input tag:

```
value="<?php echo isset($docinfo['dlastname']) ? htmlspecialchars($docinfo['dlastname']) : ''; ?>
```

This works fine, but it needs me to write something at the end of each line, which is ok if the form is small but I am working on one with at least 250 fields.

I was wondering, since the input ID is the same as the keys of the associative array, if there is an easier, more automated way to fill this cells I had two things in mind, one to import the array to java and then do

```
 document.INPUTID.value='$clientinfo[INPUTID]';
```

or something like that... but I cannot figure out the specifics and the second one was to somehow add a php command at each fields' code to write something like:

```
 value="<?php $id= $get_class($this); echo $clientinfo[$id]; ?>"
```

I dont really know how the `$get_class works` and it screwed up my code whenever I put it in there, but maybe someone could work something out to get the specific area's id?

I should mention i am very new at this, so you will find errors above and i will need a very detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have jQuery do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 <? foreach($yourArrayWithValues as $key=>$val) { ?>
       $('#<?=$key?>').val('<?=htmlspecialchars($val)?>');
 <? } ?>
</script>
```

otherwise do this with bare javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 <? foreach($yourArrayWithValues as $key=>$val) { ?>
      document.getElementById('<?=$key?>').value = '<?=htmlspecialchars($val)?>';
 <? } ?>
</script>
```

Comment: this looks exactly like what i need... for some reason tho it wont work,  
i dropped it in my page, before the head part, replaced the yourArrayWithValues  with the php array name... but it doesnt fill the cells...   
any ideas?

Comment: i even tried plain java commands like this:  
`<script  type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('dmob').value = '465412';`
or
` $('#dmob').val('123456');
 </script>`
and it still doesnt work, should i add some more specs? like .form.classname.getelementbyid? or something like that?
any ideas?

Comment: it was an ordering issue, i added a $(document).ready(function(){ before it and it works, still cannot do the array you said before, will work on it and report back

Comment: here is the final that worked:
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  
   <?php  foreach($docinfo as $key=>$val) { 
   echo "$('#" . $key . "').val('" . htmlspecialchars($val) ."');";
   }
   ?>
})
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use some form library like http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm2

They will fill your form and give some other goodies like validation. An example from a tutorial:

```
<?php
// Load the main class
require_once 'HTML/QuickForm2.php';

// Instantiate the HTML_QuickForm2 object
$form = new HTML_QuickForm2('tutorial');

// Set defaults for the form elements
$form->addDataSource(new HTML_QuickForm2_DataSource_Array(array(
    'name' => 'Joe User'
)));

// Add some elements to the form
$fieldset = $form->addElement('fieldset')->setLabel('QuickForm2 tutorial example');
$name = $fieldset->addElement('text', 'name', array('size' => 50, 'maxlength' => 255))
                 ->setLabel('Enter your name:');
$fieldset->addElement('submit', null, array('value' => 'Send!'));

// Define filters and validation rules
$name->addFilter('trim');
$name->addRule('required', 'Please enter your name');

// Try to validate a form
if ($form->validate()) {
    echo '<h1>Hello, ' . htmlspecialchars($name->getValue()) . '!</h1>';
    exit;
}

// Output the form
echo $form;
?>
```

Comment: sounds very usefull... but i do not want to rewrite the form, i already have the whole form ready with id/classes  
i want something that i will fill the existing form putting the values of the array to the correspondent id.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<? $array = array("firstfield"=>"1", "secondfield"=>2); 
foreach($array as $key=>$val) { ?>

<li class="hidden"><label for="<?=$key?>"><?=$key?>:</label><input id="<?=$key?>" type="text" name="did" style="background-color:gray" readonly="readonly" value = "<?=htmlspecialchars($val);?>" /></li>

{YOU CAN ADD YOUR JAVASCRIPT HERE AS WELL}

<? } ?>
```

Comment: vytautas, i do not wish to rewrite the whole form, i already have the fields there, i want something that will go fill their values automatically depending on their id